# Does one say "conciliate with death" or "conciliate death"?

Tags: word-usage

I am trying to say that he came to terms with death but in a more formal way. How can I put it? Is conciliate the right word to use?

Comment: Presumably we're talking about the subject's own death, not someone else's death? I notice you're talking in the past "*came* to terms with", as if the person has already died?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of other phrases for the concept you're describing:

***"he's resigned to his fate"***

***"he's reconciled to his imminent death"***

***"he's at peace with his own mortality"***

Answer (score 0):

People don't say either. [Google N-grams reports no use of either phrase](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=conciliate+with+death%2C+conciliate+death&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). Even a Google search of the phrases nets you less than 50 results for either.

"To come to terms with death" is a great phrase that carries a powerful connotation. But, other similar phrases are "move past" and "adapt."

Comment: How does one "move past" death? I'm not sure that phrase has the same meaning as "coming to terms" with death.

Comment: I think you mean *adapt to*, but any of 'adapt death', 'adapt to death' or 'move past death' are peculiar enough to draw puzzled looks. (Just the first 3 sentences would have drawn an upvote from me; so often it is the last flourish that betrays one.)

Answer (score 0):

- ***accepted ...***
- ***came to accept ...***